# jQuery click event problems when selecting by class and <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I access `<div>` or `<p>` elements by class with jQuery for a click function, it repeats the event by how many elements are in the array or stack. So, if I have 3 `<div>` elements on top of each other or next to each other, the one on the bottom, or the one to the right, will go through the event once and the one on the top or the left will go through the event 3 times.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this not meant to be done with jQuery?

[revision]
sorry if i worded this in a confusing way. here is a link... you will better understand my problem there. just add a couple new elements via the form and click on them.

http://jsfiddle.net/rNj6e/

Comment: also when accessing elements like this "event.target.id" returns a blank string, so i've been using "this.id". what is the reason for this.

Comment: I don't follow what your problem is. I thought you meant that the event was bubbling up through ancestor elements, but the HTML you've posted doesn't indicate that. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Nrg4R/2/

Comment: i figured that the reason it was happening was because jquery creates an array of the specified class elements is why i worded it like that. my mistake. what browser are you using where this works for you?

Comment: tried in FF, but jquery should be pretty much the same in all browsers. Did you try that fiddle James posted? I did things like this many times before, even with hundreds of elements with the same class for all and it always worked fine.

Comment: @DavidDan - jQuery creates an array-like object containing references to the selected elements. When you call `click` it binds the supplied function as a click event handler to all elements individually in the matched set. See the fiddle I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: i did check out the fiddle... it works fine in that. just not in my code. i'll be using jsfiddle a lot now that you showed it to me. thanks man

Comment: @DavidDan - Can you post more of your code then? Try making a jsfiddle of your own which replicates your problem. Then it will be much easier  for us to find where you're going wrong.

Comment: i guess it wasn't deeper in my code... here is a fiddle link

Comment: @DavidDan - Thanks for posting the fiddle. See my answer for an explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've posted a fiddle showing the problem, I can actually answer. The problem is that you bind the click event handler to `.dp` inside the click event handler bound to `#add`. So what happens is this:

1. You fill in the form and click `#add`, which creates a new element with class `dp` and appends it
2. It then binds a click event handler to every element with class `dp` (there's only 1, the 1 we just added)
3. You fill in the form again, click `#add`, which repeats steps 1 and 2, *so it binds another click event listener to the first `.dp` element*, and binds one to the new element.
4. Repeat as necessary, binding more and more event handlers to the existing elements every time you click `#add`!

To fix this, you need to bind the event handler to `.dp` outside of the `#add` event handler. The problem is that you're creating new `.dp` elements on the fly, so just using `.click` won't bind to elements that are not in the DOM yet. To solve that, you can use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which binds an event handler to elements matching the selector *now and in the future*:

```
$("#preview").delegate(".dp", "click", function(event){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rNj6e/3/).

Comment: perfect... thanks man... sorry about the confusion. i'll use fiddle for example code for now on

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :) Yeah, jsfiddle is a great tool!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".some_class").click(function(event){
    alert(event.target.id);
}).children().click(function(event) {
  return false;
});
```

This should prevent the click event from bubbling through the children, this happens when you click on the children contained in the div.

You are recieving a blank ID because the target of your clicks is most likely the child you clicked and you haven't given it an ID.

To prove this try...

```
$(".some_class").click(function(event){
    alert(event.target.nodeName);
});
```

which alerts you the nodeName (the name of the html tag) you just clicked.

Comment: @DavidDan After re-reading I am confused at your issue, your code shows one child in each div and tests fine, can you post the actual problematic html?

Comment: that was the link to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
$(".some_class").each( function () { 

jQuery(this).click(function(event){
    alert(event.target.id);
});

});
```

Comment: i tried this too... it didn't work for me... must be something deeper in my code

Comment: @John - This won't make a difference. Most jQuery methods are applied to all the elements in the matched set anyway, so you don't need to use `each`.

Comment: @JamesAllardice true, but sometimes it might be needed. It has happened to me once or twice. .click() no result, after changing it to .each() blah blah, suddenly works